# Listbox Vertical Scrolling Arrows

Tags: listbox, scroll, arrows

What do you check to see if the up or down arrow in the listbox vertical scroll bar were clicked.

Looked at dozens of post all over the web and no answer.

What I want to do is if they click up or down then make the next visible item in the list the selected one. Make it highlighted.

thanks all

Comment: In what programming language and platform?

Comment: C# visual studios 13  winform

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the control won't do it natively. You will need to implement it yourself. You can use this post as a guideline:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7554/Getting-Scroll-Events-for-a-Listbox

Note that you will need to handle the `WM_VSCROLL` message rather than the `WM_HSCROLL` message as depicted in the code sample.